# SSH login still ask password even though public key is added in remote machine's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I have a Raspberry pi 4 with a Linux OS & I am using a Macbook. The two machines are in the same LAN.

Raspberry pi IP address is `192.168.10.11`. I can ping the Raspberry Pi from my MacBook terminal successfully.

On my MacBook, I generated a ssh key pair under `~/.ssh/`, file names are `raspberry` and `raspberry.pub`.

In the terminal of my Macbook, I executed command:

`ssh-copy-id -f -i raspberry.pub root@192.168.10.11`

I verified that it successfully added the public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the Raspberry Pi. And I verified it by login as a `root` user in the Raspberry Pi.

Then, in a new terminal session of MacBook, I run ssh connection to the Raspberry pi:

```
ssh root@192.168.10.11
```

I thought it would not ask me password to login but I still get a password prompt asking for the root user password.  And if I enter the correct password, I can login to Raspberry pie as a root user.

But why it asks password when making SSH login from my MacBook to the Raspberry Pi? I mean the public key is there under root user's `~/.ssh/authroized_keys` of the Pi. Where do I miss?

Comment: At least with OpenSSH, non-default identity files need to be passed explicitly on the command line afaik ex. `ssh -i ~/.ssh/raspberry root@192.168.10.11`

Comment: 3 things : Does the right of the keys 600 (if not the private key isn't read at all), then why don't use ssh -i to provide the real private key while login (it search perhaps for id_rsa) and lastly did you check if root can login remotely on Rasp-pi.

Comment: Oh! yes, without specifying the private key, it would use the default `id_rsa` I suppose.

Comment: Exactly that!  I noticed alternatively I could just do `ssh-add ~/.ssh/raspberry` then the ssh connection could be established without specifying the private key `ssh root@<IP of the PI>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `config` file inside your `.ssh` folder and add `IdentityFile /home/youruser/.ssh/mykey` to set the default key to use.

After which, check that the SSH dir and its contents have the right permissions (you can run `stat --format '%a' <file or dir>`):

- `.ssh`: `700`
- `private key`: `600`
- `public key`: `644`
- `authorized_keys`: `600`

Comment: This also can be set per remote host, so individual remotes will use different keys, and yet you never need to specify them on the command line.